# JHipster gateway application SSL certificate from cloudflare setup

Tags: spring-security, jhipster, cloudflare

So I am using JHipster to build my micro service architecture. I am at a point it is almost time to fully deploy my gateway, but i have an issue.

SSL/TLS specifically i use cloud flare to proxy my public ip, and provide certificates. I use kemp for layer 7 routing incoming traffic. My app is housed inside a Kubernetes cluster. My problem is i cant get ssl/tls to work right and I don't even know where to begin on how to add cloudflare certificates to my JHipster gateway.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated I have been looking for two weeks now trying to solve it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read JHipster doc about TLS? https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#security

One point to think about is whether or not you want to expose your gateway publicly or if you prefer to put it behind a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx).

If you for the reverse proxy, you'll find plenty of resources to explain how to do it.

If you want to expose your gateway directly then it's not specific to JHipster, it's the same as for any java application, you must import your certificate into a KeyStore.

You can do it using JDK's keytool or simpler using KeyStore Explorer.

After that you might have to find a way to do it Kubernetes but I can't help here.